# JSON- Array in MongoDB with Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following JSON-Object in a Mongo database:

```
{ "elem1": { "elem2": ["elem3": {"elem4", "elem5"}, "elem6"] }}
```

I want to check, if elem4 equals to 22. I'm writing this query with Spring Data. Now I wrote the following query, but it doesn't work for me:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("elem1.elem2").elemMatch(Criteria.where("elem3.elem4").is("22")));
```

Does anyone know why my query doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your json is not valid. Please provide valid sample to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid. Please change it if you want it like this.

```
{
    "elem1": {
        "elem2": "22"
    },
    "elem3": {
        "elem4": "22",
        "elem5": "33"
    }

}
```